# What role does 一种 have in 一种似曾相识的感觉?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In 一种似曾相识的感觉, 一种 does not mean “one type of”. Removing 一种 does not seem to change anything. Comparing the following, I can’t tell any difference.

> 1. 这是我第一次来苏州，却有**一种**似曾相识的感觉。
> 2. 这是我第一次来苏州，却有似曾相识的感觉。

So what role does 一种 have?

Comment: 不同的語氣. "这是我第一次来苏州，却有**著**似曾相识的感觉。"

Answer (score 4):

种 is a classifier of 感觉

Example:

一种(a kind of -->  *uncertainty*) 似曾相识的感觉

一陣(a wave of -->  *profound*) 似曾相识的感觉

一股(a thrust of --> *strong*) 似曾相识的感觉

一絲絲 (a trace of --> *slight*) 似曾相识的感觉

More example:

有似曾相识的感觉 = have a déjà vu feel

有一种似曾相识的感觉 = have some kind of déjà vu feel (not sure what it is)

有不祥預感 = have a bad feeling

有一种不祥預感 = have some kind of bad feeling (not sure what it is)

給人淒滄的感觉 = give people a miserable feeling

給人一种淒滄的感觉 = give people a kind of miserable feeling (not sure what it is)

Answer (score 1):

**The two sentences mean the same**
The following three sentences have the same meaning

- 这是我第一次来苏州，却有似曾相识的感觉。（the shortest expression，casual，informal）
- 这是我第一次来苏州，却有**种**似曾相识的感觉。（most used,recommended）
- 这是我第一次来苏州，却有**一种**似曾相识的感觉。（the most complete expression）

---

- 这是我第一次来苏州，却有似曾相识的感觉。(feeling)
- 这是我第一次来苏州，却有**种**似曾相识的感觉。(a feeling)
- 这是我第一次来苏州，却有**一种**似曾相识的感觉。(a kind of feeling)

Answer (score 0):

这是我第一次来苏州，却有一种似曾相识的感觉。

-我来苏州，有感觉。
一种 --> counter
这是我第一次来苏州，却有种似曾相识的感觉。
-->这是我第五次来苏州，却没有那种似曾相识的感觉。